# JS: How to append array with variable into JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, string

**Given the following data:**

```
var json = [ 
{ 'myKey': 'A', 'status': 0 },
{ 'myKey': 'B', 'status': 1 },
{ 'myKey': 'C', 'status': 1  },
{ 'myKey': 'D', 'status': 1 }
];
```

I want to append **a new array with a variable "Id"**, something like :

```
var Id = "aNewLetterFunction";
json.push({'myKey':'+Id+','status':1}); //this doesn't work
```

How can I do, since the +Id+ is not natively considered as a variable ?
JSfiddle.net appreciate.

**EDIT:** [fiddle available](http://jsfiddle.net/7DdKN/)

---

I tried various things such :

```
json.push('{"myKey":"'+Id+'","status":1},');
```

or

```
var ar1 = '{"myKey":"';
var Id = Id;
var ar2 = '","status":1},';
json.push(ar1+Id+ar2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an object, don't create a JSON string:

```
json.push({
    myKey:Id,
    status:'1'
});
```

You don't want to add another value to the JSON but to the array that **can be parsed to a JSON string, but isn't a string.**

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ksXaS/)

Comment: @Hugolpz, just remember, there is no such thing a JSON object, there is a JSON string that can be converted to an object or the other way around.

Answer (score 3):

`json` is probably not a good variable name since you have an array of objects, and JSON is, by definition, a string.

That note aside, you would just construct an object literal and push that:

```
var Id = "aNewLetterFunction";
json.push({
    myKey: Id,
    status: 1 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
json.push({'myKey':Id, 'status':1});
```

You don't want a string with the variables name, but use the variable?